# django syndication: how to send a queryset containing all feeds to a template

Tags: django, django-templates, feed, syndication

I'd like to display all available feeds on one page, but I don't want to hard code each feed. Something like sending in a queryset of feeds would be perfect, like:

{% for feed in feeds %}
{{ feed.link }}
{{ feed.name }}
{{ feed.description }}
{% endfor %}

From what I understand, Feeds in the Django Syndication Framework are created as individual classes that inherit from class (feed).  This means I can't create a queryset for all feeds, only for individual feeds.

How can I send in a queryset of feeds, if they are each a different class?  Is this only possible by way of crafting a queryset from a class that references each feed using generic foreignkey relations?  Or can I actually send in a queryset of the parent [feed] class?

Bonus question: is there a simple way to aggregate a "full-feed" from all individual feeds?

Many thanks!

Comment: how do you create the query set in the first place? could you show code?

Comment: I think that the list approach is the way to go, but this doesn't answer the question of automatically forming a list of all classes that inherit from class [feed].

For now, I'll use the feed list manually defined in my urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

If you can enumerate feeds in advance you can create a list of feeds and put it into the template...

```
feeds = [feed_a,feed_b,...] 
feeds.append(feed_c)
...
```

I've **tried an approach below and it did not work**, which actually could be made to work since "related_name" only creates an accessor function and does not affect DB tables.

```
#this code does not work in Django v1
class FeedCollection(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class BloggerFeed(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(FeedCollection,related_name='feed')

class CNNFeed(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(FeedCollection,related_name='feed')
```

Django complains that accessor functions `FeedCollection.feed_set` for the two feed tables clash.